# I can't seem to prove that (p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ r) → (q ∨ r) is a tautology.

Tags: propositional-calculus

Here are my steps:

```
(p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ r) → (q ∨ r)  
¬[ (p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ r) ] ∨ (q ∨ r)   implication to disjunction  
¬(p ∨ q) ∨ ¬(¬p ∨ r) ∨ (q ∨ r)      demorgans law  
(¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (p ∧ ¬r) ∨ (q ∨ r)      demorgans law + double negation
```

I'm stuck on this last step. The only law that seemed hopeful was the distribution law but that won't even work here. I resorted to using a truth table to prove this but I really want to know if it's possible to shrink this proposition to just true to make it a tautology.

Thank you!

Comment: That's weird. Implication to disjunction seems to have failed.

Comment: Isn't implication to disjunction (and all the other steps) supposed to preserve the truthity of the statement? It turns from F under your conditions to T after applying implication to disjunction.

Comment: @JMP I looked it up and actually False on the left hand side means that the statement is true. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-would-you-explain-the-implication-disjunction-equivalence/7726

Comment: q,r false means the LHS is false and so the statement is true regardless of whether the RHS is true or false. An arrow statement is only false for $T\rightarrow F$. (I can’t explain why. I last did this in like middle school.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue as follows; I think that the steps should all be fairly easy for you to justify.

$$\begin{align*}
&(\neg p\land\neg q)\lor(p\land\neg r)\lor(q\lor r)\\
&\big((\neg p\land\neg q)\lor q\big)\lor\big((p\land\neg r)\lor r\big)\\
&\big((\neg p\lor q)\land(\neg q\lor q)\big)\lor\big((p\lor r)\land(\neg r\lor r)\big)\\
&\big((\neg p\lor q)\land\top\big)\lor\big((p\lor r)\land\top\big)\\
&(\neg p\lor q)\lor(p\lor r)\\
&(\neg p\lor p)\lor(q\lor r)\\
&\top\lor(q\lor r)\\
&\top
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you Brian for the clarification. I guess I did have to use the distribution law but it just didn't click for me. After realizing that by reading your answer, it makes much more sense.

Comment: @shim: You’re welcome; glad it makes more sense now.